# Extract all the elements within a class in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, csv, web-scraping

I have made the following, in order to extract the first element in a class:

```
if var_source == "Image":
    outcsvfile = 'Image_Ids' + file + '_' + timestamp +'.csv'
    with open(outcsvfile, 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csvfile:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile) 
            csv_writer.writerow(['ax','physical_id'])
    for i in range(len(var_ax)):    
        browser.get('https://test.com' + str(mpid) + '&ax=' + var_ax[i])
        self.master.update()
        self.status.config(text = str(i+1) + "/" + str(len(var_ax)) + " Extracting AX: " + var_ax[i])
        try:
            ph_id = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'a-image-wrapper')]").get_attribute("alt")
            print(i+1,': extract AX:',var_ax[i])
            with open(outcsvfile, 'a+', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csvfile:
                csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile) 
                csv_writer.writerow([var_ax[i],ph_id])
        except:
            print(i+1,': extract AX:',var_ax[i])
            with open(outcsvfile, 'a+', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csvfile:
                csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile) 
                csv_writer.writerow([var_ax[i],'[missing AX]'])
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I extract all the physical_ids in the same cell separated by a comma (cell B2 = "physical_id1, physical_id2, physical_id3")?
2. How can I sum the number of physical_ids exported in column C (ex: for C2 we will have 3, because in B2 we have 3 physical_ids exported)?

The source code:

```
<div alt="51d5gBEzhjL" style="width:220px;float:left;margin-left:34px;margin-bottom:10px;border:1px solid #D0D0D0" class="a-image-wrapper a-lazy-loaded MAIN GLOBAL 51d5gBEzhjL"><h1 class="a-size-medium a-spacing-mini a-spacing-top-mini a-color-information a-text-center a-text-bold">MAIN</h1><h1 class="a-size-base a-spacing-mini a-spacing-top-mini a-color-information a-text-center a-text-bold"> ou GLOBAL / Merch 1</h1></div>
<h1 class="a-size-medium a-spacing-mini a-spacing-top-mini a-color-information a-text-center a-text-bold">FACT</h1>
<h1 class="a-size-base a-spacing-mini a-spacing-top-mini a-color-information a-text-center a-text-bold"> ou GLOBAL / Merch 1</h1>
<span class="a-declarative" data-action="a-modal"><center><img class="ecx" id="51S+wTs36zL" src="https://test.com/images/I/51S+wTs36zL._AA200_.jpg" alt="51S+wTs36zL"></center></span>
<center>
<img class="ecx" id="51S+wTs36zL" src="https://test.com/images/I/51S+wTs36zL._AA200_.jpg" alt="51S+wTs36zL">
</center>
</span>
<h5 class="physical-id">51S+wTs36zL</h5>
<h1 class="a-size-medium a-spacing-mini a-spacing-top-mini a-color-information a-text-center a-text-bold" style="background:#D0D0D0">UPLOADED</h1>
<h1 class="a-size-base a-spacing-mini a-spacing-top-mini a-color-information a-text-center a-text-bold">19/Apr/2016:17:45:40</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: How about sharing the URL or a representative `HTML` sample?

Comment: added. Don't know what's that -1 for but anyway

Comment: Here's a pro tip: *never ever* share images of code (here and anywhere else you have fellow coders) as this is *absolutely* useless and epically infurating. Having said that, get rid of that image and paste the `HTML` as *plain text*. PS. That down vote is probably for that image of code. See https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: the -1 was given before I have uploaded the image. I have edited and uploaded the source on pastebin (it's too large for my post)

Comment: If your code is too large for posting in the question it is not a minimal representative example, please review  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.

Comment: .get_attribute("alt") and .get_attribute("text") and .get_attribute("h5") and browser.find_element_by_css_selector('div.a-image-wrapper') doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me and resolved both my questions:

```
    if var_source == "Image":
        outcsvfile = 'Image_Ids-' + file + '_' + timestamp +'.csv'
        with open(outcsvfile, 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csvfile:
                csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile) 
                csv_writer.writerow(['ax','physical_id','image_count'])
        for i in range(len(var_ax)):    
            browser.get('https://test.com' + str(mpid) + '&ax=' + var_ax[i])
            self.master.update()
            self.status.config(text = str(i+1) + "/" + str(len(var_ax)) + " Extracting AX: " + var_ax[i])
            try:
                ph_id = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'a-image-wrapper')]").get_attribute("alt")
                ids1 = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("physical-id")
                ids1Text = []
                for a in ids1:
                    ids1Text.append(a.text)
                nr = str(len(ids1))
                ax = ', '.join(ids1Text)
                print(i+1,': extract AX:',var_ax[i])
                with open(outcsvfile, 'a+', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csvfile:
                    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
                    csv_writer.writerow([var_ax[i], ax, nr])
            except:
                print(i+1,': extract AX:',var_ax[i])
                with open(outcsvfile, 'a+', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csvfile:
                    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile) 
                    csv_writer.writerow([var_ax[i],'[missing AX]'])
```